# jQuery UI problem with multiple IF statements

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-dialog

I definitely don't think of myself as a jQuery/javascript expert, but I know enough programming to get by - but on this project I ran into a problem where jQuery UI fails to initialize the 2nd dialog. I have 2 if statements to test before initializing each of them, but only the 1st if statement seems to be kicking in.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){  
  // regular dialog box
        $("#dialog").dialog({autoOpen: false, modal: true});
        $("#dialog_link").click(function(){
            $("#dialog").dialog("open");
            return false;
        });

  // confirm box
  if($.cookie("modal_confirm").length > 0 && $.cookie("modal_confirm")!="") {
   $("body").prepend(''+$.cookie("modal_confirm")+'');
   var g = $("#confirm");
   g.html( g.html().replace(/\+/g," ") );
   $("#confirm").dialog({ 
     modal: true,
     stack: true,
     buttons: {
      'OK': function() { window.location.replace($.cookie("confirmGo"))); (this).dialog('close'); },
      Cancel: function() { $(this).dialog('close'); }
     },
     close: function(){ $.cookie("modal_confirm",null); $.cookie("confirmGo",null);}
   }); 
  }

  // alert box
  if($.cookie("alert").length > 0 && $.cookie("alert")!="") {
   $("body").prepend(''+$.cookie("alert")+'');
   var f = $("#alert");
   f.html( f.html().replace(/\+/g," ") );
   $("#alert").dialog({modal: true, stack: true, buttons: {'OK': function() {$(this).dialog('close');}}, close: function(){ $.cookie("alert",null); }});
  } 
    });
```

In this case, the alert modal wouldn't open while the confirm opens. If I move it in front of the confirm, then the alert would open but the confirm wouldn't open.
Is this a jQuery UI problem? If so, is there a workaround?

Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Building on this answer from @dxprog, you really should run all your JavaScript through JSLint (http://www.jslint.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You had an extra parenthesis on line 18 and forgot the $ in front of (this) later on the same line. It should read:

`'OK': function() { window.location.replace($.cookie("confirmGo")); $(this).dialog('close'); },`

Used [jslint](http://jslint.com) to locate those errors.

Comment: oh sorry, that's where I had a decodeURIComponent open, and in the original code I have the right number of parentheses, so that's not the problem...any other ideas?